# JDialog and disable main window

Tags: java, swing, window, frame, jdialog

I use JDialog in my project.
When I click button in main frame JDialog frame appears and main window becomes inactive.
Is there any possibility to remain main window active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I click button in main frame JDialog frame appears and main window becomes inactive. Is there any possibility to remain main window active?

The solution: Make the JDialog non-modal either directly,

```
myDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.MODELESS);
```

or by passing the correct ModalityType into your JDialog's constructor.

```
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(myFrame, "My Dialog", ModalityType.MODELESS);
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Full Of Eels, whats the difference between `setModal()` and `setModalityType()`

Comment: @Devolus: the modal property holds a binary value since it is boolean. It has been largely superceded by Dialog.ModalityType which is an enum and can represent several different *shades* of modality. Per the Dialog `setModal(...)` method API, `"This method is obsolete and is kept for backwards compatiblity only. Use setModalityType(...) instead."`